# Manually obtain view produced by content negotiation

Tags: spring-boot

I have looked in the docs to determine how to make a call to get back the same view that content negotiation returns and I can't find out how to do this.

I have configured content negotiation to return XML and JSON which works fine as far as the response goes but I also need to 'call' content negotiation manually.

We store request/response in our DB and I would like to call content negotiation with my object and have it return back JSON/XML as it would with the response. I know I can do the work by inspecting the accept header, queryParam, and defaults; however, I would prefer to use the same method(s) content negotiation uses.

Anyone know how to manually call 'Content Negotiation' with my response object and have it determine whether it should return back XML/JSON as it would with the response?

Comment: I think the question is quite hard to answer.

Comment: After looking at the spring code, I found a fair solution that will resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some debugging I figured out what works for my case.

With my manually configured content negotiation listed below.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    public static final String FORMAT_PARAM = "format";

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false)
                  .favorParameter(true)
                  .parameterName(FORMAT_PARAM)
                  .useJaf(false)
                  .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                  .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                  .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

}
```

I can inject the ContentNegotiationManager into the service that needs this information and make a call to resolveMediaTypes and this will get me the media type that will be used in the response.